# kafka stuck with num.stream.threads and max.poll.record

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have one Kafka consumer with the following configuration.

num.stream.threads=10
max.poll.record=90

Is the consumer consumes 90 records from topic for 10 threads or it is 10*90=900 messages in the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

**max.poll.records**

> The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll().

The Kafka Streams configuration entry StreamsConfig.NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG indicates how many stream threads to generate for this application instance.

A StreamThread is an actual Java thread with its own unique Kafka consumer and producer instances.

Each StreamThread is assigned tasks to perform. A Kafka Streams application's capacity is defined by the total number of StreamThread instances available overall running instances of the application.

The KafkaStreamsinstance is started triggering all StreamThreads to start.
Each StreamThread then uses its own KafkaConsumer to subscribe to all source topics.

Since each thread is an individual Kafka consumer instance, each thread would consume 90 messages ie 900 messages in total.

Source : https://medium.com/@andy.bryant/kafka-streams-work-allocation-4f31c24753cc